# Should you group achievements by organization or include them project wise?

Tags: resume, india

Lot of international or impactful resumes I see, mention the achievements or duties performed group at organization level under *Work Experience* section.

Example:

```
Organization name    
 - Work done
 - Achievements
```

Indians usually don't follow this, and write those bullet points under each project that they worked on withing the organization. Yes Indian resumes are lengthy (often) which I don't like.

Example:

```
Organization name    
 - Project 1
      - Work done
      - Achievements
 - Project 2
 - so on...
```

Former one definitely looks precise and help grab attention of reader. Downside is that reader can't really tell if you did/ achieved that stuff in just one project or multiple.

On the other hand, Indian format gives definite idea about number of projects the candidate has worked on and what he specifically did or achieved in those. Downside is that such resumes become lengthy and reader may not even go through whole document.

How to best balance this?

Note - I am not saying the former format will/ does not work in India. It can be considered if it has all the relevant information. 2 pages work best no matter where you are!

**Edit** (I am not able to add comment)

@Mister Positive

1. What is `resume` tag intended for then?
2. I am not asking on how to or what to write in resume! I am just trying to find an approach to balance two formats.
3. I already have 3 page resume, and trying to reduce it further to 2 pages without loss of important information. And hence seeking advice.

Comment: @MisterPositive - We dont do specific resumes but we definately help with how to write an effective resume.

Answer (score 1):

Write your CV for those who will read it. If they have certain expectations, then meet them.

Give them what they want, rather than what you think they ought to want.

There's not much to say, beyond that.

Answer (score -1):

> Former one definitely looks precise and help grab attention of reader.
>   Downside is that reader can't really tell if you did/ achieved that
>   stuff in just one project or multiple.
>
> On the other hand, Indian format gives definite idea about number of
>   projects the candidate has worked on and what he specifically did or
>   achieved in those. Downside is that such resumes become lengthy and
>   reader may not even go through whole document.
>
> How to best balance this?

In the US at least, nobody wants to see a lengthy list of project details.
The first format is strongly preferred.

If you still feel compelled to communicate the number of projects you worked on, a single line would be more than enough:

- Worked on 7 major projects

Answer (score -1):

You should always tailor your resume to the company and the position you are applying for.

A good resume is no more than 2 pages long and holds all of your relevant information so that recruiters can get a good overview at a glance.

As for the tailoring aspect: Imagine you are looking to become a Chef. You could highlight and perhaps elaborate on the aspects of your other jobs that directly relate to cooking food. Things on your resume that don't really add any value to you as a chef you could still mention but in a far more condensed form.

**Try to relate to the recruiters; add the information that is relevant to them, leave out the clutter. Choose the first option.**